# Limit on Number of Google Spanner Read-Only Replicas

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Spanner's documentation indicates that there are two read-write replicas per read-write region in a multi-region configuration of Spanner. Is there a limit (compute aside) on the number of read-only replicas per read-only region?

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Spanner does not have a published limit on the number of read-only replicas (either per-region or within an instance configuration as a whole).

However, note that when you create an instance, you select one of the existing instance configurations -- you can not define your own custom replication topology that pieces together different numbers of read-only replicas.